# How do I load mtl files into parent object?

Tags: texturing, edit-mode, import

I created a file on my laptop's built in 3d builder, and a friend suggested that i transfer it to Blender to change it from obj to dae. I noticed that the obj file has a mtl, which (I assune) is the texture/color of my object. I only used the base texture and recolored it. How do I load the mtl for this mess[![my attempt at mesh]? I've tried the previously mentioned suggestions but they didnt help

Comment: Which previously mentioned suggestions? Otherwise will will just repeat them

Comment: I checked the suggested posts when I created this thread, but nothing they suggested either worked or made sense to me. Kinda looking for a "For Dummies'

Comment: .mtl is the companion file to a .obj file. So the only way to load an .mtl is by importing the .obj which has a reference to the .mtl . If this is a concern try creating a new Blender file and importing the .obj accepting the defaults for the .mtl (check for error messages in the console) and then save that .blend file as your material library. In your original file append it (File->Append) select the material.

Comment: @rob thank you for clarifying the issue, but what seems to be happening is Blender isnt even registering the .mtl file when i import the .obj. I've tried several times and received the same result. So how do I go about importing the .mtl file once the .obj file has been loaded? I've imported the object at least 15 times and have yet to see an option to accept the .mtl as default.

Comment: Just tried appending (once i found it on the file tab *facepalm*), but received an error message that I cant use the .mtl because it isn't a library file. guess I missed a step: converting a .mtl file to a Blender library file. Is it possible?

Comment: Start with a new Blender file. Import the .obj and make sure the .mtl comes in with it. Save this .blend file as material_library.blend. Then open up your original .blend with the Mesh and File->Append material_library.blend and the material will then be available to you.

Comment: @ rob what if the mtl file isnt uploaded with the obj, as seems to be happening whenever i try loading an obj from 3d builder?

Comment: If the .mtl exists then Blender should include it when you import the .obj. If it fails there should be a clear error message, but you may only be able to see it in the console, Window -> Toggle System Console.

Comment: @rob AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python
(  0.0000 sec |   0.0000 sec) Importing OBJ 'C:\\Users\\wyldh\\3D Objects\\Easter eggs for sl 4.0.obj'...
  (  0.0072 sec |   0.0072 sec) Parsing OBJ file...
    (  1.7198 sec |   1.7126 sec) Done, loading materials and images...
        Material not found MTL: 'C:\\Users\\wyldh\\3D Objects\\4.0.mtl'
        Material not found MTL: 'C:\\Users\\wyldh\\3D Objects\\Easter'
     had to parse it down a bit but this is what i see.

Comment: basically i'm not seeing anything i can identify as a clear error message but still not able to locate any textures based on the .mtl file. is it something i did wrong when saving the file?

Comment: you can ignore the first bit about hz. The message says "Material not found MTL: 'C:\\Users\\wyldh\\3D Objects\\4.0.mtl". Does that file exist and is it accessible? Better to edit your Question with the text for readability. The .obj and .mtl files should be text files so you can open them up in notepad and check the paths. Most likely a file/s are not where they should be.